# LWJGL Automatic Native Picker

Tags: java, linux, windows, macos, lwjgl

In LWJGL, (I am on a mac), I am making a program in it but as I debug/run my code, it requires the LWJGL OS X natives to run.

Same goes for Windows, Linux or anything else but I want it to be a little bit like the game Minecraft which was made in LWJGL.

You start the game and it automatically picks your operating systems natives.

Is there a way I can do this so I dont have to switch around manually on different operating systems?

Please share your source if you know!!

Comment: You could check out [libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) which handles all of this for you (and lets you compile for Android, iOS and web to boot).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at this: http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/Distributing_Your_LWJGL_Application.html.

It says that you can set the path to your natives by calling the following at the beginning of your main method:

```
System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", path);
```

By doing some OS detection you should be able to load the right natives, like so:

```
if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")) {
    // Windows
    System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", new File("lwjglFolderLocation/native/windows").getAbsolutePath());
} else if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Mac")) {
    // Mac OS X
    System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", new File("lwjglFolderLocation/native/macosx").getAbsolutePath());
} else if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Linux")) {
    // Linux
    System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", new File("lwjglFolderLocation/native/linux").getAbsolutePath());
} else if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Sun")) {
    // SunOS (Solaris)
    System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", new File("lwjglFolderLocation/native/solaris").getAbsolutePath());
} else {
    throw new RuntimeException("Your OS is not supported");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of LWJGL 3 there is a SharedLibraryLoader that handles loading the correct natives for you. It extracts natives from jars in the classpath, so you can for example bundle all natives in a single jar or have a separate jar for each native.

The jars have to be on the classpath, so when you distribute your program as an executable jar you have to set the `Class-Path` manifest attribute correctly.

The loader should be active by default, but you can explicitly activate it with

```
Library.initialize();
```

It works by extracting the natives from the jars into a temporary directory and loading them from there. If you want, you can change the temporary directory name and path through the `SHARED_LIBRARY_EXTRACT_DIRECTORY` and `SHARED_LIBRARY_EXTRACT_PATH` [`Configuration`](http://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/system/Configuration.html) properties.